# Android - How do i reach the built in heart rate monitor?

Tags: android

I'm working on building an app, and some of the newer phones are starting to have built-in heart rate monitors.

But I really can't find anywhere on the internet on how to access this. Does anyone have any idea of how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a Samsung Device, you might want to try the Samsung [S Health Service SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/s-health-sdk).

What kind of phones are you looking at?

Comment: Thank you, I've figured out something my self in the meantime :)